# match between two files and merge the output using awk

Tags: python-3.x, awk, sed

I have two files.First column is common between the both files and I would like to merge the file and generate the output where its copy the first file third column every time in second file whenever there is match.

file1

```
412234;mark
413234;raja
```

file2

```
412234;value1
412234;value2
412234;value3
412234;value4
413234;value1
413234;value2
413234;value3
```

Output file

```
412234;value1;mark
412234;value2;mark
412234;value3;mark
412234;value4;mark
413234;value1;raja
413234;value2;raja
413234;value3;raja
```

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve  their own problems so kindly do add the same kin your question and let us know then.

Comment: Why is `413234;value1;raja` in the output? Or any `raja` values in the output? I don't see `413234` in the `file2`.

Comment: sorry , yes true , just corrected the files. 413234 & 412234 is common between both the files but third column is different.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F';' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in a){print $1, $2, a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

explanation:

`-F';'` means that AWK will use `;` as field separator;

`BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}` set the Output filed separator, used by print function;

AWK parse all files sequentially, the condition:

```
FNR==NR
```

is true only when parsing the first file.

While parsing file1, it saves a vector `a` with first match as index and second match as value;

`a` is expected to be

```
a[412234] = mark
a[413234] = raja
```

`($1 in a)` is the condition to met, true when first match on file2 is found on vector a.

If true then execute:

```
print $1";"$2";"a[$1]
```

that prints matches from file2 and the value of the vector `a`, saved from file1

----- EDIT

In case file1 contains multiple lines with same index, you need to save all distinct values in a vector and then scan the whole vector for multiple matches on file2

```
awk -F';' ' \
function vlen(a){n=0; for(i in a) n++; return n;}  # helper function defined here \
function contained(val, vect) {found =0; for (x in vect) { if(vect[x] == val) found=1}; return found}   # helper function defined here \
BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} # Set output field separator \
FNR==NR{n=vlen(a); a[n]=$1; b[n]=$2; next} # scan file1 and save all indexes and value in different vectors \
{if(contained($1,a)) { for (i in a) { if (a[i] ==  $1) { print $1, $2, b[i]}} } else { print $1, $2 }   } # for each line in file2, scan the whole vector a looking for a match \
' file1 file2
```

here we are defining the `vlen` and `contained` helper functions

Comment: great its worked , Apparently I found out in output that file1 could also have following example 412234;mark & 412234;raja and its only pick raja and ignore the mark . Do you have any proposed solution to fix the the problem.

Comment: Good luck! :) `awk -F';' 'FNR=NR{ if (FNR==1) {while (match($0, /\w*;\w*/)) { idx = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); v=idx; sub(/;\w*/, "", idx); sub(/\w*;/, "", v); $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH); a[idx]=v;}; next }} ($1 in a){print $1";"$2";"a[$1]}' file1 file2`

Comment: You should mention that the script in your comment would require GNU awk for `\w` to mean what you intend. Or just use `[[:alnum:]_]` for portability. Also, just a typo - that first condition should be `FNR==NR` (*==*).

Comment: Use OFS as it exists to be used rather than hard-coding `;` multiple times: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{print $1, $2, a[$1]}' file1 file2`

Comment: Thank you and sorry , its still giving same output and just picking up raja from file1 and failing to similar to following if file1 & file2 has following information  
     
file1  
412234;mark  
412234;raja  

file2  
412234;value1  
412234;value2  
413234;value1  
413234;value2  

output  
412234;value1;mark  
412234;value2;mark  
412234;value1;raja  
412234;value2;raja  
413234;value1  
413234;value2

Answer (score 0):

Would you try the following:

```
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"}
NR==FNR {
    c[$1]++
    a[$1,c[$1]]=$2
    next
}
{
    if (c[$1]) {
        for (i=1; i<=c[$1]; i++) {
            $3=a[$1,i]; print
        }
    } else {
        print
    }
}' file1 file2
```

Result with the `file1` and `file2` provided in the OP's last comment:

```
412234;value1;mark
412234;value1;raja
412234;value2;mark
412234;value2;raja
413234;value1
413234;value2
```

If the index in the 1st column (such as `412234`) appears more than once
in file1, we need to preserve the existing value in the 2nd column
(such as `mark`) without overwriting.
Then an array `c` is introduced to count the occurrences of the index.

Note that the order of the result differs from the OP's expected output.
I hope it is acceptable.